# how to tackle large data in redis

Tags: redis

My pc have 3G memory,and I store data into redis.I write data to disk via dump.rdb. I found when dump.rdb is about 1.5G,redis will shut down,why that?

and when I input **info** in redis-cli,I found all my memory are spent by redis.

how to tackle that?

I use `32bit, ubuntu 12.04.`

if I add more memory,32bit machine only can hold 4G memory,so if I will add more 5G data，how to tackle that much dat?

thx guys.

Answer (score 2):

You're hitting the 32 bit process memory limit.  2GB of the address space is reserved for the kernel, leaving only 2GB left.  You then read 1.5GB, and presumably do some more stuff with it that involves allocating more memory, and somewhere in this process, you run out.

If you want to be able to use more than that you'll need a machine with more ram and a 64 bit operating system.

Comment: I have 3 2G 32bit machines,could I setup redis cluster to solve that?

Comment: Maybe, as long as you wouldn't need to load the whole dataset at once on any one machine.  If you have any machine with 64 bit capable hardware, you might just want to install 64 bit ubuntu on it and give it a large enough swap space that redis doesn't run out of virtual memory.